# ERROR: Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio

I am trying to connect firebase to my android application in android studio, I'm getting the following error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.15/google-services-4.3.15.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.15/google-services-4.3.15.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

this is my app\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flashchat"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

this is my android\build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and Yes, I added google-services.json in the app directory.
I checked out the other solutions mentioned here but so far I could not get any valid solutions.

Comment: Try changing the network, might be due the network restriction

Answer (score 0):

Do following

1. Open android module in android studio
2. Do build clean
3. change gradle JDK

[image]

4. Do change to embedded JDK
   [image]

5) Do gradle sync and try again.