# Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, crashlytics

I'm using Flutter to build an apk for my application.

Flutter doctor result:

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.10.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f468f3366c (8 days ago) • 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
Engine • revision cdbeda788a
Tools • Dart 3.0.6 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

Recently, the apk build always failed because of this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
     Versions that do not match: 1.0.0
     Required by:
         project :app > project :firebase_crashlytics > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0
```

Here are the Firebase packages I'm using:

```
firebase_analytics: ^10.4.4
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.4
firebase_core: ^2.15.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.8.3
firebase_storage: ^11.2.5
firebase_auth: ^4.7.1
cloud_functions: ^4.3.4
```

Gradle versions:

```
Android gradle plugin version: 7.4.2
Gradle version: 7.6.2
```

Please help, because I could not find any solution for this new problem!

Here is the gradle android level:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.7'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the gradle app level:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.14.0'
    }
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myappid.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Please attach app gradle and project level gradle file .

Comment: @AkshayGupta Done, Gradle versions: Android gradle plugin version: 7.4.2, Gradle version: 7.6.2

Comment: No, please share images of whole both gradle file

Comment: @AkshayGupta images has been added

Comment: Please check out this answer and check
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/76709856/19665498

Comment: @AkshayGupta Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app, same error :(

Comment: Please add gradle file as a text not image.

Comment: @AkshayGupta ok, Done

Comment: probably i have solved this issue.Have you used onsignal in your code?

Comment: @AkshayGupta yes i do have OneSignal for notifications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254609/discussion-between-akshay-gupta-and-virus-x).

Comment: Please join the chat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After plenty of debugging i come to know that the issue caused by onesignal library simply remove them because in newer version of onesignal it was deprecated for more info please follow below link

[Onesignal link](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin)

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you found it's useful.

Comment: wow, dude. it seems to work just removing the OneSignal references from `build.gradle`. I thought this issue was being caused by my flutter upgrade. and, not less important: what we're supposed to use in place of OneSignal since we removed it from the project? what solution are you adopting to continue receiving push notifications?

Comment: @ebragaparah Hi I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution to still using push notification from onesignal

Comment: @wahyu, hey! sorry for the delay in responding. all the issues gone when I removed the occurrences of one-signal from my `build.gradle` (app level). I just kept one-signal-plugin in one place.

in my `build.gradle` (android level), I am using one-signal-gradle-plugin inside 'dependecies' block, like:

classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.14.0, 0.99.99]'

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for now is to use older versions of Firebase packages.

Open Android Studio project terminal

1. Run "flutter clean" command
2. Run "pod cache clean --all" command
3. Run "flutter pub cache clean" command

(Delete also pubspec.lock and podfile.lock files)

Now use the Firebase packages you want with these versions in pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase_analytics: 10.4.3
  firebase_crashlytics: 3.3.3
  firebase_core: 2.14.0
  cloud_firestore: 4.8.1
  firebase_storage: 11.2.3
  firebase_auth: 4.6.3
  cloud_functions: 4.3.3
```

Make sure to remove "^" before the package version number.

4. Run "flutter pub get" command
5. Run "cd ios" then "pod update" commands

Done.

Note: if you are using OneSignal for notifications, try the accepted answer.