# How can i solve Firebase crashlytics problem that any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

We have a project includes One signal and Firebase Crashlytics. But now our project is not complying because of crashlytics and firebase sessions version problem. I already make changes about One Signal but the problem still goes on and we are unable to continue project. Would you help us solving problem?

I already tried this, not solved my issue.
[One Signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76730332/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-google-firebasefirebase-sessions1)

Problem is:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).

Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Versions that do not match:
  - 1.0.2
  - 1.0.1
  - 1.0.0
Required by:
    project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.1
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.9.0.300'
    //    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.0"
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

build.gradle(android)

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.14.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
```

We want to application to build up with upgraded version.

Comment: According to the link you shared, it seems like OneSignal has been deprecated. Can you please remove the plugin completely and try again?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes unfortunately our project is depend on one signal already. we have to solve this problem with one signal integration.

Comment: OneSignal has a Flutter SDK now, and according to their installation steps, you don't need the Android plugin anymore. See their instructions here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes, I am not sure if the docs are outdated, but, in one video has the instruction of adding the plugin on the android/build.gradle. but, for some reason, I removed the plugin part and my app is working fine, I sent a test push notification and I receive it perfectly. thanks

Comment: @ebragaparah Glad it worked for you :) I also added as an answer, as I hope it will help more folks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on their GitHub repo, it seems like the OneSignal Android plugin has been [deprecated](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin), so it should be safe to remove it from the project. You can also refer to the new [Flutter SDK setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup) instructions on the official OneSignal documentation.