# Update to Firebase BoM later than 32.1.1 in Android App

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-performance

I am trying to update all firebase libraries I have in my Android project to 32.3.1.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
```

I cannot make it work to a later version than the 32.1.1. The issue I have is this:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Versions that do not match:
  - 1.0.2
  - 1.0.1
  - 1.0.0
Required by:
    project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.3
    project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.4.1
```

The weird thing is that the latest `firebase-sessions` version is 1.0.2 as it is mentioned [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-sessions).

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76738277) is relevant to Flutter this made me to fix the issue. Also the [OneSignal official docs](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin) mention that the gradle plugin was deprecated.

So, I removed these two lines from my project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
...
classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.13.4'
```